In Awesome, how to create a symlink to the wallpaper set by Variety?
In Awesome Window Manager, how would I modify the set_wallpaper script from Variety Wallpaper Changer (shown below) to create a symlink in ~/.cache/current_wallpaper to the newly set wallpaper image?
# Awesome Window Manager
# Be sure to start variety when you start awesome, such as by adding it to ~/.xinitrc
# NOTE: This config will change the wallpaper after your current awesome theme sets it.
# As such, the theme's wallpaper will briefly appear before being replaced with Variety's wallpaper.
if [[ "$XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP $DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID $DESKTOP_SESSION $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" == *"awesome"* ]]; then
    echo "for s in screen do require(\"gears\").wallpaper.maximized(\"$1\", s) end" | awesome-client
fi

